# Jwt authorization in react app without storing token in local storage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, jwt, authorization

actually I am going to implement jwt authorization in my first react app and i have gone through many articles and all of them suggesting storing the token in local storage which somehow I am not finding it secure as the token is visible. So two solution came into my mind which obviously is not the best solution that y i am here asking the question
Solution 
1. Generating the jwt token on my react side on every API request, but for doing this I have to use secret key on my client-side which obviously is a BAD IDEA exposing the secret key.
2. Having two express app one running the react app and one running the api, the api call from my react app will hit the react express side in where i will generate the token and hit the actually api with the token, i know its little confusing hope you guys understood what i am trying to explain.

That's what I have thought and I know both the solution are not a good one, so it would be very helpful if some of you suggest me how u have done authorization in you app

Answer (score 0):

1. Indeed, not a great idea to expose your secret key
2. Why use multiple express apps for this? You can authenticate directly in your "react express" app

[This](https://medium.com/@faizanv/authentication-for-your-react-and-express-application-w-json-web-tokens-923515826e0) is a great article on React, Express and JWT

About storing the JWT in the browser (you primary concern), there isn't a definitive answer. This [article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) explain benefits and cons of storing in cookies or in local/session storage. But you need to store it in the browser also, as you need to send it with each request.

Token being visible is not necessarily a security thread. The principle is that it cannot be manipulated, even when someone has it (for example to change the expiration date).